# Ruby array not updating when changing values in loop

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I wrote this code block (mind all the print statements, I couldn't figure out where the issue was).

```
  tablet_arr = []
  objects.map do |backup_file|
    puts backup_file
    if backup_file == "desc.xml"
      puts "finding"
      tablet_arr += find_files('../..' + backup_file)
      puts "Temp"
      p tablet_arr
    end
    client.upload(backup_file)
  end
  puts "End"
  p tablet_arr
```

I wanted `tablet_arr` to end with all the values that had been added to the array during the loop. During this loop, when I print "Temp", the array correctly combines and prints as expected. However, when I display the array at "End", `tablet_arr` is still set to `[]`. I know if this were in C++ this would be more of a case of pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value, but it doesn't look like there's any way to use pointers in Ruby. Is there some other way I should be doing this to ensure that `tablet_arr` actually holds onto this new value after the loop completes?

I have tried declaring the initial array with `Array.new` as well as `Array.new(4)`.
I have also tried using `.concat()` over the `+=` operator, and also using a temp variable before adding it. The thing is, it had no problem properly concatenating the two arrays, it just didn't hold onto these values.

Comment: Aside from your questionable use of `map`: If the `p tablet_arr` after the `puts "Temp"` shows the updated array, the `p tablet_arr` will also show this - provided that you really show your code. If not, post a **reproducible** example (i.e. with a concrete value for `objects`, and replacing `client.upload` and `find_files` by suitable dummy functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to me how this could happen. `+=` should be doing what you expect when both sides are arrays. Are you sure the desired (array) value is being returned from `#find_files`, and you're not just seeing a debug log from inside `#find_files`? Or is your actual code different in some way to what you've put here? Is the assignment being customised by defining `#tablet_arr=`?

As a sidenote, here are some things I'd change in the code:

- Inside the conditional, `backup_file` must be `'desc.xml'`, which would result in `'../..' + backup_file` producing an invalid path, '../..desc.xml' (slash missing)
- `#map` returns an array. If you're not going to use that return value, switch to `#each`

Comment: Sorry, in regards to the side notes, I edited part of the path when posting since it's actually a lot longer, it does produce the correct path, but a good point nonetheless. I also had temporarily switched each to map but am still using each for this.

Comment: I don't know about any customized assignment. When I tried by initially setting it to Array.new(4), it correctly has `[null, null, null, null, 1, 2, 3, 4]` (assuming `[1, 2, 3, 4]`  was the return of `find_files`). I'm only using these print statements for debug, so I shouldn't be seeing any other debug logs. I guess I can look more into `find_files`, but then I really don't know why it would be correctly concatenating inside the loop but then not saving any of it.

Comment: I also tried changing to instance variables by using `@tablet_arr` but I'm pretty new to Ruby so I'm not super familiar with what this is for, but this didn't change anything anyways. But yeah like there's other stuff in the code but this is the bottom of the file so there shouldn't be anything that's affecting this that I didn't already put.

Comment: @jroj00 I'd suggest trying to produce a minimal piece of code which can be run by others to reproduce the core issue. Often in the process of simplification and slimming things down to that point, the problem reveals itself =)

Comment: Also, `map` does not retain anything (but that's not the problem). The OP should use `each` in place of `map`.

Comment: Wow okay, thanks for the help and confirming this should work. I had this in another loop and fully expected the `.each` loop to execute in order. I totally missed that it wasn't and as a result the last one was showing the iteration that should never have anything. Since I had so many things printing out, I didn't follow this correctly. I'm really going to need to learn to debug correctly. I appreciate the support though, sorry about that.